# Headphones not detected with Alienware 17R3

Tags: sound, 18.04, alienware

I am new to Linux, not by choice but I had a couple of stroke a few years ago and have had to relearn everything.

I have an Alienware 17 R3 with Sound Blaster Recon 3Di sound card. I get no sound via the headphones (but the computer "recognizes" when the plug gets plugged in/out), but the behavior of the sound only comes out of the internal speakers, regardless headphones are plugged in or not. I have the same problem with any version of Linux (Mint 18.1, 18.2 and 18.3) and now the currently Ubuntu-Mate 18.04 LTS. I have read previous specific others having the same problem, but they are on the 16.04 instance of previous similar Linux distributions. Where can I find the same problem/resolution with this version on 18.04 LTS? (Detail system info follows!)

Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction!

---

```
System:  Host: Ubuntu-Mate18 Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
         gcc: 7.3.0

Desktop: MATE 1.20.1 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu1) info: mate-panel dm: lightdm
         Distro: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Machine: Device: laptop System: Alienware product: Alienware 17 R3 
         v:1.3.10 serial: N/A
   Mobo: Alienware model: 0GH72M v: A00 serial: N/A UEFI [Legacy]: 
         Alienware v: 1.3.10 date: 12/12/2016 Chassis: type: 10

    CPU: Quad core Intel Core i7-6700HQ (-MT-MCP-) arch: Skylake-S rev.3 
         cache: 6144 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 
         vmx) bmips: 20736 clock speeds: min/max: 800/3500 MHz 1: 3214 MHz 
         2: 3302 MHz 3: 3206 MHz 4: 3188 MHz 5: 3174 MHz 6: 3297 MHz 7: 
         3221 MHz 8: 3224 MHz

Graphics:  Card-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 
           8086:191b
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip- 
           ID: 10de:13d8
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: modesetting,nvidia 
           (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.02hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 970M/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.6.0 
           NVIDIA 390.48 Direct Render: Yes

Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus- 
           ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a170

Sound:     Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-20-generic
```

Comment: There are two jack inputs. I think one is dual mic/headphone dynamically recognized. Which input jack are you using?

Comment: I have tried both. I realize one is labeled Microphone and the other is Headphones & Microphone and both of them do the same thing.

Comment: You are one step ahead of me, I own the same laptop since Oct 2017 and haven't tried headphones yet. I'll add that to my to-do list.